# Dockerfile does not pull from Nexus

Tags: dockerfile, nexus

I have configured *daemon.json*, so I can pull images in my local machine from our Nexus image repository.

**daemon.json** details:

```
{
"registry-mirrors": ["http://jenkins.DomaiName.com"],
"insecure-registries": [
  "jenkins.DomaiName.com",
  "jenkins.DomaiName.com:8312"
],
"debug": true,
"experimental": false,
"features": {
  "buildkit": true
}
}
```

The configuration works fine and I can pull the images using:

```
docker pull jenkins.DomaiName.com/ImageA
```

In my dockerfile, I can use the image since I have already pull it.

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM jenkins.DomaiName.com/ImageA

VOLUME ./:app/

COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN apt install unixodbc-bin -y
RUN apt-get clean -y

EXPOSE 9999:9999 1433:1433
ENTRYPOINT python -u flask_api.py 9999
```

The dockerfile also works fine and it can pull the ImageA.

I was assuming that dockerfile should still work fine even if I had not pull image A from Nexus repo using *docker pull jenkins.DomaiName.com/ImageA*. So what I did, I removed the imageA from local images and run dockerfile again. But in contrast to my assumption dockerfile did not pull the image from Nexus repo because it could not find the image. Does the dockerfile uses different daemon.json file than the one I modified in /etc/docker?

Comment: What is your `daemon.json` content? How are you pulling the given image manually when it works? What is the content of your Dockerfile? How are you building your image from that file? How is your docker registry configured on Nexus side? Does it need authentication? Are you talking about a hosted registry of a registry you use as dockerhub mirror? As is it is not possible to answer your question. Please edit it and add enough details.

Comment: Why is your pull image different then the docker file image?

Comment: Sorry my mistake @Shmuel, I just updated it.